# golang: can't execute t.execute

Tags: go

I'm trying to make an Handler to update one row each time getting data from a submitt button,
here is my code:

```
func RowHandler(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    if req.Method != "POST" {
        http.ServeFile(res, req, "homepage.html")
        return
    }
    Person_id := req.FormValue("Person_id")

    stmt, err := db.Prepare("update Cityes set Status='right' where  Person_id=?")

    if err != nil {

        log.Print("error ", err)
    }
    _, err = stmt.Exec(&Person_id)

    t, err := template.ParseFiles("city_update.html") //hier i just want to show a text in html Page

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = t.Execute(res, "/city_update")

}
```

Comment: what is the current behaviour of the code snippet that is shared ?

Comment: i'm getting this: multiple registrations for /

Comment: for `/` :  Looks like your route is   not correct . Try printing/logging the formdata and see what is coming.

Comment: i have added answer assuming your problem is only with the  `Execute` function . Please update the question  clarifying your isuue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here instead of following

```
err = t.Execute(res, "/city_update")
```

pass data to be used to fill your template as send arguement to `Execute` not string. [link to doc](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Execute)

For example .

```
err = t.Execute(res,struct{ID string}{Person_id})
```